# Why do I get an error when loading the package tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

When I run `library(tidyverse)` I see a list of all the attached packages and below that there is an error message:

> "Error in -library(tidyverse) : invalid argument to unary operator."

**Why?** 
I am using the latest version of `tidyverse` (1.2.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not actually doing: `library(tidyverse)` but `-library(tidyverse)`, note the hyphen (or minus sign) just before the call to `library`.

The call to `library` actually runs fine but then R tries to pass the returned value of `library` (a character vector with the list of attached packages) to the unary operator `-`, hence the error.

Just fix that typo, i.e. remove the `-`. :)